# Is There any keyboard Shortcut to override method of super class in visual Studio Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overriding

I can override method of interface but in case of simple class i could have any option to override method of super class using any keyboard shortcut. I have to do that by manual copy paste method from super class.

Comment: not it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing an abstract class then the red underline will be shown below the class that is implementing that class, simply move the cursor there and press **(Ctrl + .)**.

And if you are extending any class where its methods are not mandatory to override, but you want to override then simply type the first letter of the method that you want to override.